# Table cell click which will redirect to an updated table?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an API which has a bunch of data in it. I should be able to click the first column with the header "Symbol" which then goes to a completely new, updated table. This is how it looks [before the cell click](https://imgbox.com/9h6pgzWa). This is what happens though [after I click a cell](https://imgbox.com/NvTD5Ggk). The page goes blank even though the URL has updated based on my code. What I want to happen is after the cell click, the table updates with new column headers and row values, based on the "symbol" I clicked, with data filling the table from the API.

When I click on a cell, it goes to a brand new page based on that cell (so like /history/A), but how am I supposed to create a .js file for 500 different cell values?

I am using a useTable hook with react-table-v7, and I have a separate Table.js file for the layout.

```
function Stocks() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  axios(`http://localhost:3000/all`)
    .then((res) => {
      setData(res.data);
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err))
}, []);

const columns = useMemo(
  () => [
    {
      Header: "Stock search",
      columns: [
        {
          Header: "Symbol",
          accessor: "symbol",
          Cell: ({ row }) => (<Link to={{ pathname: `/history/${row.original.symbol} `}}>{row.original.symbol}</Link>)
        },
        {
          Header: "Name",
          accessor: "name",
        },
        {
          Header: "Industry",
          accessor: "industry",
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
  []
) 

return (
  <div className="Stocks">
    <Table 
    columns={columns}
    data={data} 
    />
  </div>
);
}
```

I have no errors, warnings or issues on my dev tools either.